# How can I stop my subform from autoscrolling when an item is being edited?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

We have an old MS Access app I am editing, and one of the forms contain a bunch of subforms. The subforms all contain staticly positioned objects, and should not ever scroll.

My problem is that if a user selects a TextBox towards the bottom of the subform and starts to edit it, the form auto-scrolls to bring that TextBox closer to the top, which basically cuts off the top part of the form.

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When form `MySubForm` is inserted into form `MyMainForm`, it is contained in a container: the `SubForm` object.
If `MySubForm` is larger than its container, the user can scroll within the container to reach any part of the subform.
In your case, just open `MySubForm`in Design view, and make sure its size (width and height) does not exceed the size of the container (the `SubForm` object located in `MainForm`).
If you do that , there will be no reason to scroll.

Comment: Thanks :) I really hate working with Access and avoid it whenever possible

Comment: You're welcome. I like Access, and find it quite efficient. My trouble is rather the opposite:  try doing the same things with VS, and beeing impatient :-)

Comment: Once you are familiar with access, you can do things very efficiently.